# List the most liked posts

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Using Graph Explorer API call with the following:

```
me?fields=posts{likes.summary(true).filter(stream).order(ranked)}
```

I get my posts, and who likes a summary containing the total:

```
{
    "posts": {
        "data": [{
            "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "likes": {
                "data": [{
                    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                }],
                "paging": {
                    "cursors": {
                        "before": "...",
                        "after": "..."
                    },
                    "next": "..."
                },
                "summary": {
                    "total_count": 35,
                    "can_like": true,
                    "has_liked": false
                }
            }
        }, {
            "id": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
            "likes": {
                "data": [{
                    "id": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
                    "name": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
                }],
                "paging": {
                    "cursors": {
                        "before": "...",
                        "after": "..."
                    },
                    "next": "..."
                },
                "summary": {
                    "total_count": 30,
                    "can_like": true,
                    "has_liked": false
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

In this way he brings me the amount of Likes per post. How to list the posts with more likes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the short, somewhat displeasing answer but... there is no way to do this with the API. You will need to collect the results and order them manually in your PHP script.

Comment: Just found some similar answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703532/facebook-graph-api-sorting-search-results http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448554/facebook-graph-search-order-results